# Batch file echoing duplicate lines

Tags: batch-file, duplicates, echo, login-script

I have a handful of batch files running at users' login via GPOs and a couple of them that create text/batch files with various info are exhibiting odd behavior. Specifically, these batches run at login are echoing the same value(s) multiple times into the target files. As an example:

```
ECHO @echo off > \\server\share$\%username%.bat
ECHO set minimized=true >> \\server\share$\%username%.bat
ECHO start /min cmd /C "path-to-program" %computername% >> \\server\share$\%username%.bat
```

Seems pretty straightforward, right? Yet this batch is producing a file that contains:

```
@echo off 
set minimized=true 
start /min cmd /C "path-to-program" computer
start /min cmd /C "path-to-program" computer
```

This isn't my only .bat doing this, but it's all the same concept - echoing a bunch of info into a file and somewhere along the way it's as if parts of it are getting run multiple times.

Has anyone seen this before and/or have any suggestions as to what could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
(ECHO @echo off
ECHO set minimized=true
ECHO start /min cmd /C "path-to-program" %computername%)>"\\server\share$\%username%.bat"
```